# Json string as input parameter to ksoap

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I have a soap web service and I am consuming that web servie from a android device using ksoap.
I have a java object and I used google gson library to convert that object to json like below

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
String agr0=gson.toJson(myobject);
```

Now I am adding thia string as input parameter to ksoap request as

```
SoapObject request= new SoapObject();
 request.addPreperty("arg0",arg0);
```

When I call my web service using HttpTransportSE call method I get EOFException I beleive it is because of special characters in arg0 string. 
At the server side I am using gson to parse json string to myobject.
How to resolve this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well SOAP uses XML as its data format.  Not JSON.  I would imagine that the issue is that you are getting XML back from the service and the "special characters" you're referring to are coming from that.

Comment: the web method that I am calling has void as its return type

Comment: I debugged the issue and it is in HttpTransportSE class line no 196 I am using ksoap2 assembly 3.1.1 with dependencies jar

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were passing the JSON object TO the service.  In that case, I have to ask, why are you passing a JSON object?  Why not just add the individual properties of the object to the request properties?

Comment: That would be too cumbersome as I have many properties I have model classes on server and in android app so converting these model objects using gson both on server as well as android app